# Ctrl+Space doesn’t work in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Ctrl+Space doesn’t work in NetBeans 8.0 , i have tried clearing the cache located in Netbeans 8 directoyr but it didnt help , also there is no .netbeans forlder rather .nbi folder. Please help i need to turn this auto complete/import thing on.

Comment: Off-topic `Tools >> Options >> Editor >> Code Completion`

Comment: it was working before but suddenly it stopped , the above path is already selected

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ctrlspace-has-been-bound-to-invoke-some-input-method-and-does-not-work-in-ema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had what seemed like a similar issue, in my case another program was stealing the "Cntr+SPACE" combo, by registering a global short-cut in Windows.

You could test this by going to Tools -> Options -> Keymap, search for "Show Code Completion Popup".

If it is not assigned to Cntrl + Space , set it to Cntrl + Space and see if that fixes it. If it is already assigned to Cntr + Space, assign it to something else and see if the newly assigned shortcut works.